# How to have a Select Query for access table Integer value?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm using vs2010 and access table. I wish to have a Select Query with integer values. But I'm receiving error as "DataType Mismatch" error. Can anybody show me a correct one?

My Codes

```
SvINVNo = 0;
SvINVNo = Convert.ToInt32(richTextBox1.Text);
String SelctInvQury = "Select * from invoicemst where invoice_no= ' "&SvINVNo &" '";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you shoul do like this

```
String SelctInvQury = string.Format("Select * from invoicemst where invoice_no= {0} ", SvINVNo) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Because, assuming `invoice_no` is an integer, you're comparing that with a string. Change your query to remove single quotes:

```
String SelctInvQury = "Select * from invoicemst where invoice_no="+ SvINVNo;
```

That said your parameter is a number but it comes from a RTF control. Is it right? Moreover you do not any check for user input so if it's not an integer it'll throw an exception. IMO is much better to handle that (invalid user input is a common case):

```
int SvINVNo;
if (!Int32.TryParse(richTextBox1.Text, out SvINVNo)) {
    // Invalid user input
}
else {
    String SelctInvQury = "Select * from invoicemst where invoice_no="+ SvINVNo;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use

```
Select * from invoicemst where invoice_no="& SvINVNo &"
```